# Unable to open class

Tags: java, netbeans

Provided is what my Netbeans program looks like right now, I've been trying to google this for hours but have found nothing that has helped. For an assignment I am supposed to open the 'Dealership.class' class and modify it, when I do the following nothing happens;

Double clicking the .class file

file > open file > dealership.class

dragging dealership.class into the editor window

When I double click the file I get an error from Netbeans saying "Cannot open, no source".

Can anyone tell me why this is occurring?

[What my Netbeans looks like via Gyazo](http://gyazo.com/c8833eaa4cc45b4b02228a746f3be1b1)

Comment: You haven't attached the source code

Comment: 1. Did you check if the file exists? 2. Are you actually supposed to be modifying a .class file and not a .java file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't open the class file, open

```
Dealership.java
```

Instead, that is the uncompiled text version that is readable

Comment: @ScurieDS No problem ;) have fun in your Java programming life

Answer (score 0):

### If you don't have `dealership.java`,

There is No way when using normal IDEs.

[Use JD to decompile the file to a `.java` and open it.](http://jd.benow.ca/)